# Найти дочерний элемент по классу на чистом JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom

```css
var elements = document.querySelector('.list-group-item');
```

```html
  <li class="list-group-item">
    <a href="">link</a>
    <div class="filmname">
      filmname
    </div>
  </li>
```

Как на чистом JavaScript найти дочерний элемент по имени класса, когда в выборке имеем доступ только к родителю

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Например так:

```js
var parent = document.querySelector('.list-group-item');
var child = parent.querySelector('.filmname');

console.log(child);
```

```html
 <li class="list-group-item">
    <a href="">link</a>
    <div class="filmname">
      filmname
    </div>
  </li>
```

Comment: Это очевидно, но вопрос был как достать элемент из родителя

Comment: Мой ответ, и еще один, схожи. Значит не так и очевидно. Мне например и сейчас непонятно, что значит «достать элемент»?

Comment: ой извиняюсь всё правильно, это я не так понял ответ сначала, да это то что я искал спасибо.

Comment: @AlexandrKazakov Ваш ответ в точности соответствует вопросу,  +1.

Comment: Уточнение: таким образом будет найден не дочерний, а любой вложеннный, хотя в большинстве случаев подойдёт.

Answer (score 4):

Можно получить все дочерние элементы из пропорции `childNodes`. А затем пройтись по ним и узнать у кого есть определенный класс.

```js
var elements = document.querySelector('.list-group-item');
var notes = null;
for (var i = 0; i < elements.childNodes.length; i++) {
    if (elements.childNodes[i].className == "filmname") {
      notes = elements.childNodes[i];
      break;
    }        
}
console.log(notes);
```

```html
<li class="list-group-item">
  <a href="">link</a>
  <div class="filmname">
    filmname
  </div>
</li>
```

Comment: Спасибо, я понял, у меня была такая идея, но я надеялся есть способ проще)

Comment: @Dmitry Ну есть и другие варианты, смотрите другой ответ. может будет полезен.

Comment: Лучше children - нет смысла перебирать не элементы.

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector

Метод `querySelector` определен для всех DOM элементов:

```
var childElement = parentElement.querySelector(".list-group-item");
```

Обратите внимание на точку перед названием класса.

Comment: Это будет любой вложенный, необязательно дочерний.